# How to get the value from a dropdown button that uses @Html.DropDownListFor tag helper in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dropdown button which populates the values using the HTML tag helper **@Html.DropDownListFor**
The code for the button is:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="valueSetParent">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Sets, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle", @style = "font-color: white" })
</div>
```

I have a javascript function which requires the **Id** value of the option that is selected in the dropdown button.

```
function xyx=z(e, testId, Id) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#Modal').data('test_id', testId).data('id', Id).modal('show');
    }
```

But when I run the code, the value of **Id** does not get sent to the function and shows *NULL* in this case. How do I make sure the Id of the selected value in the dropdown button is sent to the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get the Id of selected item,`new SelectList(Model.Sets, "Id", "Name")` made the Id be Value,Name be Id of Selected Item.You can use `$("select").val()` or `$("#Id").val()` to get the Id in js rather than pass data to the function.
Here is a demo:

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult DropDown() {
        DropDownModel dropDownModel = new DropDownModel();
        dropDownModel.Sets = new List<Set1> { new Set1 { Id="s1",Name="set1"},new Set1 { Id="s2",Name="set2"} };
        return View(dropDownModel);
    }
```

View:

```
<h1>DropDown</h1>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Sets,"Id","Name"), new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle", @style = "font-color: white" })
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="selectId()">select</button>
</div>
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectId() {
        alert($("select").val());
    }
</script>
}
```

Result:
[image]